# Como o PDO lida de maneira mais performática

Tags: php, pdo, desempenho

#### Finalidade:

Selecionar uma única linha com `LIMIT 1`

#### Uso Interno:

Os `selects` recebem só parâmetros internos

Não precisa de `PREPARE` pois não há dados externos de usuários

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=A.com;dbname=B; charset=utf8", "C", "PW");

exemplo 1:
$con = $pdo->query("SELECT id,titulo FROM cursos WHERE cod=1 LIMIT 1");
foreach($con as $row) {
echo $row['id'].' - '.$row['titulo']; 
}
```

#### Exemplo 2:

```
$con = $pdo->query("SELECT id,titulo FROM cursos WHERE cod=1 LIMIT 1");
$con->execute();
$sel=$con->fetch();
echo $sel['id'].' - '.$sel['titulo'];
```

#### Exemplo 3:

```
$con = $pdo->query("SELECT id,titulo FROM cursos WHERE cod=1 LIMIT 1")->fetch();
echo $con['id'].' - '.$con['titulo'];
```

A linha selecionada contém 80 colunas (com ou sem dados)

Os 3 funcionam OK, mas tenho dúvidas de qual usar.

Se houver uma outra forma, mais reduzida ou mais rápida.

Comment: Não tem mudanças a nível de MySQL, apenas de PHP. Note inclusive que o SQL passado para o SGBD é o mesmo. A pergunta então se torna "como o PDO lida de maneira mais performática".

Comment: Eu diria para você medir a performance de cada uma das 3 maneiras. Não tenho base sobre PHP/PDO para falar com propriedade, mas você poderia testar em uma massa significativa de dados para ver o quão performático é cada uma. Repete algumas centenas de vezes, tira a média e o desvio padrão e usa o que você achar melhor (normalmente menor média e com menor desvio)

Comment: Vc recomenda alterar o texto da pergunta? A sua é mais objetiva? estou aprendendo a usar o Stack, agradeço a atenção

Comment: Falei mais para você mesmo perceber qual o foco da questão. Nem tanto sobre o uso do site, mas sim para que você tenha a ideia correta do que esteja acontecendo. O mundo fica muito mais fácil e direto quanto se sabe com o quê estamos lidando. Sobre o uso do StackOverflow, já vi textos melhores. Eu recomendo editar o título, já que não há real diferença entre `select`s, mas em recuperar os dados no PHP, mas também não tenho uma sugestão de título melhor. O que mais me incomodava que era a tag eu já substituí

Comment: Se retorna apenas um registro, não vejo motivos para usar o `foreach`, descartando o exemplo 1. Entre os exemplos 2 e 3, a única diferença que vi foi o `execute`, porém como funciona sem no exemplo 3, ele realmente é necessário no exemplo 2? Se não for, os exemplos serão iguais.

Comment: @Geo A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 6):

Se a performance é relevante para sua aplicação use uma linguagem compilada de tipagem estática e de preferência que utilize a filosofia de abstração de custo zero. Tipo C, C++, Rust, eventualmente C#, Kotlin, Java, D, Go, Swift. Não utilize uma linguagem de *script*. Para PHP a performance é irrelevante.

O maior custo aí, e com larga margem de diferença, provavelmente algumas ordens de magnitude, é a consulta ao banco de dados, então se precisa de melhor performance pense em estratégia de cache ou rearquitetar a aplicação, os ganhos costumam vir mais do *design* do que detalhes no código.

Se ainda quer algum ganho de execução saia do PDO. Quase ninguém precisa dele e ele custa bem mais caro que o acesso direto ao cliente do banco de dados.

Dito tudo isso, o terceiro é mais simples, direto e até por executar diretamente menos coisas provavelmente é o mais rápido (não será fácil medir a diferença de performance). Digo provavelmente porque só conhecendo a implementação do PDO para saber, mas só usei a palavra para não parecer que o simples fato de ter um comando a menos já faz tudo ser mais rápido, pode ser que a falta dele gere outras consequências que torne mais lento, mas nesse caso é altamente improvável, e se acontecer fuja do PDO.

Então algo assim seria melhor:

```
$dados = $mysql->query("SELECT id, titulo FROM cursos WHERE cod = 1")->fetch();
echo $dados['id'] . ' - ' . $dados['titulo'];
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/GetData.php).

Mas dependendo de onde for usar pode haver ganhos fazendo de outra forma. Não se pode analisar performance sem contexto.

Tem como melhorar mais fazendo algo totalmente diferente disto, mas só no caso concreto com muita informação disponível dá para saber o que.

E funcionar é diferente de estar certo. Não que isto esteja errado, não tenho como afirmar sem contexto, mas fica o alerta.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Comment: Gostei da sua sugestão e testei. Mas o resultado não parece. A conexão está OK. Será que cometi algum erro? $mysql = new mysqli('h','A','pw','B') or die ("Falha");
if (!$mysql){echo'Erro'.mysqli_error();exit;}else{echo'Conectado';}
$dados = $mysql->query("SELECT id,titulo FROM cursos where cod=1")->fetch();echo $dados['id'] . ' - ' . $dados['titulo'];

Comment: Aí já é outro problema, faça outra pergunta com bastante detalhes sobre ele.

Comment: Ok, (não há mais o que detalhar, está tudo no comentário acima) Agradeço a explanação e analogia com carros. Para mim: Ferrari = Performance com qualidade. Obrigado.

Comment: @Geo Sem execute não vai funcionar.

Comment: [Fazendo par com o 147](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZwkbD2IHKQ) :D

Comment: Vou mudar meu apelido para "Esponja", porque qualquer tempinho sempre fico absorvendo conteúdo ! Merece ênfase: "Se ainda quer algum ganho de execução saia do PDO. Quase ninguém precisa dele e ele custa bem mais caro que o acesso direto ao cliente do banco de dados."